# How to validate jquery datePicker dates?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two input boxes, `startDate` and `tilldate`. I am using jQuery datepicker.
The problem is when a user selects the `startDate` then in the `tillDate` only two days should be enabled for selection. For example `01/04/2015` then `tilldate` can be either same date or next date, `02/04/2015`.

```
<td><input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate"  ></td>
<td><input type="text" id="tillDate" name="tillDate"></td>
```

```js
$(function () {
    var setDate;
    $("#startDate")
    .datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select Date",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '0',
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#tillDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
            setDate = $("#startDate").val();
            alert(setDate);
        }
    });    

    $("#tillDate").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select Date",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: setDate + "2D",
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
        }
    });

    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having with your code?

Comment: In the `onSelect` function of your `startDate` picker, you are not specifying a `maxDate` property for the `tillDate` picker. You are only specifying a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per my understand you need only two days on till date. plz check the bellow code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
     var setDate;

    $("#startDate")
    .datepicker(
         {
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select Date",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate:'0' ,
       onSelect: function (selected) {
             setDate = $("#startDate").val();
             var maxDatevale=new Date(setDate);
             maxDatevale.setDate(maxDatevale.getDate()+1);
             alert(maxDatevale);
            $("#tillDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", setDate)
             $("#tillDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDatevale)


        }
    });    

    $("#tillDate").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select Date",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: setDate + "2D",
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
        }
    });

    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Plz accept this answer so that in future it may helps others @RajuYadav

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i got it right, you just dont want the user to pick a date thats before start date value?

If so, why dont you just put start date value in a global and then retrieve it in your tilldate function. Once you have the value you can just check if tilldate value is not a date before start date , if so just clear the input.

But your going to have to probably validate start date as well.